# Cannot invoke method render() on null object in Grail while email sending

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am using **mail:1.0.1** plugin for mail sending

but while sending mail its gives me an error..

Source :-

```
def serviceMethod(EmailModel mailObj) {
        PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer;
        try{
            sendMail {
                to "abc@gmail.com"
                subject mailObj.subject;
                  html groovyPageRenderer.render(template:"myMailTemplate", model: [mailObj: mailObj])


            }
        } catch (Throwable th) {
                    th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the gsp page as email body then you can send it like:

```
def mailService

def serviceMethod(EmailModel mailObj) {
...
    mailService.sendMail {
        to email
        subject "subject"
        body(view: "/_template", model: [mailObj: mailObj])
    }
...
}
```

**EDIT...................................................................................**

Just inject `PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer` globally, like

```
import grails.gsp.PageRenderer
class TestService {
    PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer

    def getText() {
        String s = groovyPageRenderer.render(template: "../first/temp", model: [name: 'user1690588'])
        println "Content = ${s}"
    }
}
```

Comment: mailService.??? i m using mail:1.0.1 plugin.. so is this important for this pluging as well

Comment: You can send mail directly, `sendMail...`

Comment: groovyPageRenderer.render(template:"/layouts/_emailparse", model:[mailObj: mailObj]) with this code it showing me an same error

Answer (score 1):

I think you are calling Service Class(.groovy) method from java class.
by using object of EmailService class.
So you cant get Object of PageRenderer class.
for this 
Create **SpringsUtil** Class in src/java and define constant object of EmailSerevice. like this

```
public class SpringsUtil {

    public static ApplicationContext getCtx() {
        return getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return (ApplicationContext) ServletContextHolder.getServletContext().getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T getBean(String beanName) {
        return (T) getApplicationContext().getBean(beanName);
    }


    public static final String EMAIL_SERVICE = "emailService";
//  public static final String INVENTORY_REORDER_SERVICE =  "InventoryReorderService";

}
```

create object of Service class and call method

**EmailService emailService = SpringsUtil.getBean(SpringsUtil.EMAIL_SERVICE);**

Comment: Thank you atul for your answer